# Writing to specified memory location

Tags: c++, memory, pointers

I have just started learning C++ so I may be way off the mark with this one but go easy on me.

What I want to do is to write to a memory address that I specify - if that's possible?

The code I am using is:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    int i = 100;
    int* p = &i;
    cout << p << "\n";
    cout << "Writing" << "\n";
    int* w = (int*)0x28ff18;
    *w = 101;
    cout << *p << "\n" << "Done";
    return 0;
}
```

The address I get for `i` is `0x28ff18`, so is it possible to write to that location by specifying this address? Rather than use `*p = 101`. Obviously what I am using doesn't change it, I don't know where or if it's writing `101`.

Any simple explanation or help is much appreciated.

Comment: Is that a local address in your memory space ?

Comment: This doesn't sound safe to me..

Comment: @dystroy I think so, it's the address it outputs to the console when I return the location of `i`.

Comment: You are assuming that everytime you run your program it will be same address, which need not be true.

Comment: It sounds easier to write `i = 101`. What are you really trying to achieve ?

Comment: If I remember correctly, in linux, the 1st 1GB is reserved for the kernel - so it is guaranteed to fail under it.

Comment: @dystroy I simply want to write a value to the address I give it, rather than using the pointer, if thats possible.

Comment: @amit: [It is pretty complicated, actually](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory)

Comment: @phresnel: I know about virtual memory, again it has been a long time since I looked at the kernel, but *if I remember correctly* - the first 1GB of *virtual memory* is reserved for kernel...

Comment: @phresnel: Also, acording to [this](http://linux-mm.org/VirtualMemory): `"Every physical page of memory up to 896MB is mapped directly into the kernel space...."` for these addresses the mapping is the identity function, so the requested OP is violating access, since it is in kernel domain.

Comment: @amit I'm not sure if its relevant, but this is on Windows, does the same apply?

Comment: @BaliC: I have no idea how it works in windows, it is definetly not safe and not advised, but I don't know if it is *guaranteed* to violate access.

Comment: Although I agree that this is unsafe, the program works as listed for me using GCC and on linux. (Of course, the memory address had to change)

Comment: @jedwards Out of interest, where would the addresses begin that were after the first 1GB of virtual memory, as amit was discussing.

Comment: @amit: But we aren't discussing kernel mode programs here, are we?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On most computers and with most compilers, something like this will probably work. But the C++ standard does not guarantee anything about this.

For example, when I compiled and ran your code using MSVC++ on a Windows machine, every time the address was different. You cannot expect it to be the same between different runs of the same program.

Also note that the integer you are storing the pointer value in should be large enough (e.g., a 64-bit integer when you have 64-bit pointers). Use uintptr_t if you want to do this (thanks larsmans for pointing this out).

Comment: Yeah I think the whole idea of not getting the same location is where it went wrong, I tried it again and it gave the same address so it worked, but I guess it can change everytime.

Comment: `uintptr_t` is the standard type for storing pointer values in integer variables, not `size_t`.

Answer (score 3):

The address of `i` may be different from one run of the program to the next. This is very unsafe. Please don't do this; there is a reason why memory addresses are hidden behind the abstraction of pointers in C++.

The only places where you would see memory address literals are very small embedded systems and operating system kernels/drivers.

Answer (score 3):

Although it is possible to write to a specific memory location, it does not necessarily mean that it is safe to do so.

In environments where you own the entire memory space (specifically, embedded systems) it is commonplace to write to a specific memory address to perform memory-mapped I/O operations. In situations when the operating environment is in control of your memory space, it is unsafe to write to any memory that has not been allocated to your program.